# Model of Mathematics

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, geometry, elementary-number-theory, trigonometry

Although my question isn't congruent with the technical nature of this forum, I felt it necessary.

Is anyone aware of a written model with visual examples that maps out the structure of mathematics? Not the MOST specific information but the basics of each concept from Algebra, Geometry and Trigonometry all the way down the line to Calculus (and how they relate)?

Such a model may be helpful for visual learners to build a better view of math as a whole.

Answer (score 3):

It is not a model per se, but the below video is fantastic and the map at the end is super cool:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OmJ-4B-mS-Y

Here is the accompanying map image: 
[image: Map of Mathematics]

Comment: Very cool @qbert looking for something a little more specific though, describing equations and process briefly

Comment: @NathanTaylor ah ok, I don't know of anything. Sorry!